# Optimizing with Trust Region Method to any minimum

Tags: python, optimization

How could I optimize, using the confidence region method, if for example I start from a saddle point and the algorithm goes towards a minimum that I determine in the beginning?

Part of the algorithm:

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Trust-Region Methods Jorge Nocedal & Stephen J Wright. 
Numerical Optimization, second edition.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------'''
def trm(xk, alfa, deltak, maxiter=100, maxdelta=100.0, etha=0.25, tol=1e-1):
    k = 0
    xk0 = []
    xk1 = []
    fks = []
    ks = []
    while True:
        fk = func(xk)
        gk = grad(xk)
        Bk = hess(xk)
        pk, deltak = subproblem(gk, Bk, deltak)
        
        rhok = (fk - func(xk + pk)) / -(np.dot(gk.T, pk) + 0.5 * np.dot(np.dot(pk.T, Bk), pk))
        if rhok < 0.25:
            deltak = 0.25 * deltak
        else:
            if rhok < 0.75 and la.norm(pk) == deltak:
                deltak = min(2* deltak, maxdelta)
            else:
                deltak = deltak
        if rhok > etha:
            xk = xk + pk * alfa
        else:
            xk = xk
        
        # print('-------------------------')
        # print('fk:', fk)
        # print('|gk|:', la.norm(gk))
        # print('iter no.:', k)
        # print('-------------------------')

        xk0.append(float(xk[0]))
        xk1.append(float(xk[1]))

        fks.append(float(fk))
        ks.append(int(k))

        k += 1
        if la.norm(gk) < tol or k > maxiter:
            print("End point:", xk)
            print("Energy:", fk)
            plot_energy(ks, fks)
            plot_countour(xk0, xk1)
            plt.show()
            break
    
    return xk0, xk1


def subproblem(g, B, delta):
    b, Q = la.eigh(B)
    f = np.dot(Q.T, g)
    lam = -min(b)
    if abs(f[0]) > CLOSE_TO_ZERO:
        phi = lambda x: (1 / delta) - (1 / np.sqrt(sum((f / (b + x))**2)))
        sol = root(phi, lam)
        lam = sol.x
        p = np.zeros((N_COORDS))
        for i in range(N_COORDS):
            p += -(f[i] / (b[i] + lam)) * Q[:, i]
        delta = la.norm(p)
    else:
        tau = 0
        for i in range(1, N_COORDS):
            tau += (f[i] / (b[i] - b[0]))**2
        tau = np.sqrt(abs(delta**2 - tau))
        p = np.zeros((N_COORDS))
        for i in range(1, N_COORDS):
            p += -(f[i] / (b[i] + lam)) * Q[:, i]
        delta = tau
    
    return p, delta
```

Complete algorithm: https://github.com/earturor/Trust-Region-Method/blob/main/trm_optimizer.py

Here is for example an image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sgYJ.png)
where this algorithm starts from a saddle point and then when minimizing it goes to point C, however the question would be: how can you lead the algorithm to minimize from a saddle point to a minimum at point A?

Comment: If this is something that you fully understand but are having trouble turning into code, then I suggest clarifying what you do and don't know; if you don't know how you would do this conceptually, let alone with code, then this isn't a code question, but a mathematical one, would it not be? So, StackOverflow would not be the right place to ask this if your question doesn't have to do with the actual programming implementation.

Comment: I agree with you @Random Davis, it is a mathematical concept where this principle comes from, however I have not found information about it and I have to use my available resources, in this case one of them is Stack Overflow.

Comment: StackOverflow is a resource for programming help; not general help. If your "available resources" are depleted, then that doesn't mean you can start using resources for a purpose other than their intended one. I was implying that you might want to consider seeing if something like https://math.stackexchange.com/ could be helpful; but you'll have to make sure the question is in-scope and on-topic for that site.